# Javascript Math Function for Dynamic Div's style

Tags: javascript, math

Hey guys i'm trying to edit a dynamically created div.
And I need the MarginLeft style value of the div to be determined by a var.

I'm struggling to create the math function.

I'm only including a snippet of the code for simplicity's sake.

```
var i = 0;
function onClick() {
i++;
var mathfunc = (-260 x i) - -15;
newdiv.style.marginLeft = mathfunc;
}
```

The var mathfunc is what's causing it too fail.
I've tried a variation of the mathfunc code, but it still failed:

```
var math1 = -260;
var math2 = -15;
var math3 = math1 x i;
var mathfunc = math3 - math2;
```

Comment: You need to start from basics. Check available arithmetic operators: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators. `var math3 = math1 * i;`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use x for multiplication. You need *, just like with pretty much any calculator.

```
var i = 0;

function onClick() {
    i++;
    var mathfunc = (-260 * i) - (-15);
    newdiv.style.marginLeft = mathfunc;
}
```

You really need to start from basic though...

EDIT : You might want to specify parenthesis between the operator (-) et the number (-15) or js won't be happy :). http://jsfiddle.net/56gtpzm6/

Comment: Thanks for the tips buddy. (: 
Issues fixed... Was just the *.